# Create Pre Chat Records (Person Account) using Live agent Mobile SDK

Tags: mobilesdk

We are implementing the Live Agent functionality on both website and mobile applications.
The pre chat form should search for the Person Account Email Address in Salesforce, If it does not exist, create new one.

From the website version, We are able to create the Person Account records, as for the mobile version, records are not created.

After debugging the transaction, Salesforce is always searching in the Contact object even though we are defining the Account object as ChatEntity.
And in order to test our code, we have changed the ChatEntity to contact and that worked fine.

[In the android sdk documentation :](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.service_sdk_android.meta/service_sdk_android/android_chat_send_custom_data.htm)

only Cases and Contacts examples are given. Nothing is mentioned for other objects.

Is person Accounts supported in the Live Agent sdk ?

Answer (score 0):

Service Chat is a separate team and product from the Mobile SDK. I think you should post your issue here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/ServiceSDK-Android.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you. We are able now to create the Person Account records. We missed some line in our code.